# Linux and multi perl versions

Tags: linux, perl

I have a server running SUSE Linux that included Perl 5.18 (64-bit) as the base perl version. I have an older application using Perl 5.8 (32-bit) that I would like to migrate to the new server however the new server does not have access to the internet. Can I do this migration of all 5.8 modules without using CPAN?

A lot of internet support cases indicate that I can point to the 2nd instance of perl, but when doing a test, it keeps grabbing the 64-bit version perl. I've looked into perlbrew, but can't download and install it on my server. Is there any comprehensive list of what environment or system setup that would be required to use the older 5.8 version?

When doing perl -v from command line it returns 5.18. When I adjusted Path variable putting home directory where perl binary is for 5.8, I get error "perl: error while loading shared libraries: libperl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

user@servername:/home/user/bin $ /home/user/bin/perl -v

/home/user/bin/perl: error while loading shared libraries: libperl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: (You shouldn't need to adjust the path. You should be able to simply do `/path/to/perl -v`.)

Comment: Can't even do `perl -v`? That install is pooched. Reinstall it. (If the files simply got moved around, this might be fixable by moving them back. But that's a big "if", and basically requires knowing what got moved where.)

Comment: Are you sure that you need Perl 5.8? Perl is generally pretty good at maintaining backwards compatibility. Have you tried running your application's test suite under Perl 5.18 to see what happens? I'd bet that fixing the few problems you might find will be quicker than trying to get an obsolete Perl version up and running.

Comment: I don't have the module binaries for each of the 20 modules installed on my old system. And my server does not have access to CPAN/Internet to do the installs. I was hoping to just re-point from the base install of perl to my old one copied from old server.

Comment: Re "*And my server does not have access to CPAN/Internet to do the installs*", That part isn't an issue. You could download the distros you need using another machine. You could even download [all of CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN::Mini)!

Answer (score 3):

Some of the files of your Perl installation are missing. Without knowledge of what was done, there's no practical way of fixing this other than reinstalling Perl.